# Logarithm sum inequality?

Tags: inequality, summation

I am going over Durret's probability textbook and one of the proofs uses the inequality

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2\log k} \leq \frac{1}{n\log n}$$

But, as with much of the textbook, gives no explanation. I was thinking you could take one of the $k$'s out front to and then integrate $1/k\log k$ but that doesn't seem to be of much help.

How can I show this to be true (rather than just take Durret's word for it)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prove the following inequality $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}\log k}\leq\frac{1}{n\log n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855324/how-do-i-prove-the-following-inequality-sum-k-n1-infty-frac1k2-log) – found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3Dn%2B1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%5E2%5Clog%20k%7D%20%5Cleq%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5Clog%20n%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an integral estimate for the series:
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k^2\log k} \leq \int_n^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2\log x} = \int_{\log n}^{+\infty} \frac{dt}{te^t} \leq \frac{1}{\log n} \int_{\log n}^{+\infty} e^{-t}\,dt=\frac{1}{n\log n}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Very straightforward.

Comment: We can also do better: $\int_n^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2\log x} \leq \frac{1}{\log n}\int_n^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{1}{n\log n}$.